# Playwright, Selenium, etc.. Вопрос про специфику работы данных инструментов

Tags: test-automation

Делаю тест:
1.Зайти на страничку
2.Нажать на кнопку сортировки и выбрать "По новизне"
3.Сделать паузу (3-5 сек)
4.Забрать комментарии в массив

Проблема в том, что когда захожу на страницу, кнопка сортировки выставлена "По умолчанию".

Когда выбираю "По новизне", делаю паузу и забираю комментарии, то, забираются комментарии, как будто кнопка выставлена "По умолчанию" и в массив заходят именно в этой последовательности, а нужно, чтобы по новизне были отсортированы. Проблема как я понимаю в DOM-дереве и Playwright, Selenium видят "старую" версию DOM'а, потому что данные подгрузились динамически.

Как правильно обрабатывать такие моменты? Как заставить Playwright и Selenium видеть измененную структуру HTML?

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, чтобы ограничить его конкретной проблемой и указать достаточно подробностей, чтобы найти адекватный ответ.